# Pointers in switch case

Tags: c, function, pointers

I need to pass a char * pointer and use it in switch case to perform some opertaion.For example if I pass 'A' then I need to get the average of the numbers and if I pass 'S' then I need to get the sum of the numbers. I am not able to figure out the error in the code. Can we perform comparison operations on pointers ? Look for the code for further explanation.

I need to use switch case only to solve this.

```
double sum_n_avg(double,double,double,char*);
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    double a;
    double b;
    double c;
    char letter;

    scanf("%lf",&a);
    scanf("%lf",&b);
    scanf("%lf",&c);
    scanf(" %c",&letter);
    printf("%c,%lf,%lf,%lf\n",letter,a,b,c );
    sum_n_avg(a,b,c,&letter);


    return 0;
}



double sum_n_avg(double x,double y,double z,char *m)
{

    printf("%c\n",*m );
    printf("%lf\n",z);
    printf("%lf\n",y);
    printf("%lf\n",z );


    int temp;
    if(*m==97 || *m==65)
    {
        temp=1;
    }
    else if(*m==115|| *m==83)
    {
        temp=2;
    }
    else{
        printf("Try again\n");
    }
    switch(temp)
    {
        case '1':
             printf("%lf\n",(x+y+z)/3.0);
            break;

        case '2':
            printf("%lf \n", x+y+z);
            break;

        default:
            printf("Enter correct input parameter..Try again\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're passing an `int` into your switch and comparing it to a `char`. Change your code to `case 1` and `case 2`.

Comment: `'1'` and `'2'` are `int` in C. (But different ints than `1` and `2`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood correctly you are speaking about using variable m in a switch statement in function sum_n_avg. You can write the following way

```
switch ( *m )
{
case 'A': case 'a':
   printf("%lf\n",(x+y+z)/3.0);
   break;

case 'S': case 's':
   printf("%lf \n", x+y+z);
   break;

default:
   printf("Try again\n");
   break;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use `case 1: case 2:`  instead of `case '1': case '2':`

`temp` is an `int` and `'1' and '2'` are `char`

Comment: In C '1' and '2' are of type int. 1 and '1' are also completely different and are not exchangeable